# Select dropdown with 2 choices from foreach

Tags: user-roles, user-registration, php

I have a problem. I need to list only 2 roles: customer and shop_manager. 1. How can i do that with this script?

```
add_action( 'register_form', 'myplugin_register_form' );
function myplugin_register_form() {

    global $wp_roles;

    echo '<select name="role" class="input">';
    foreach ( $wp_roles->roles as $key=>$value ):
       echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value['name'].'</option>';
    endforeach;
    echo '</select>';

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**in_array**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check if the name of the role is either customer or shop_manager

```
add_action('register_form', 'myplugin_register_form');
function myplugin_register_form() {

    global $wp_roles;

    echo '<select name="role" class="input">';
    foreach ($wp_roles->roles as $key => $value):
        if ( in_array( $key, array('customer', 'shop_manager') ) )
            echo '<option value="' . $key . '">' . $value['name'] . '</option>';
    endforeach;
    echo '</select>';

}
```

Comment: But, this code showing empty list.

Comment: Before you updated to my code, can you paste the text you were getting for your select dropdown

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand. Can You explain? What text can i paste?

Comment: Your inital output, the select box before my code.

Comment: But, it is: echo '<select name="role" class="input">

Comment: This is my code:

Comment: The output, i mean can you post the generated select box?

Comment: generated selext box is empty:

Comment: <select name="role" class="input"></select>

Comment: The output of your own code not mine

Comment: <option value="administrator">Administrator</option><option value="editor">Editor</option><option value="author">Author</option><option value="contributor">Contributor</option><option value="subscriber">Subscriber</option><option value="customer">Klient</option>

Comment: REST:
<option value="shop_manager">Klient hurtowy - brązowy</option><option value="translator">Translator</option><option value="wholesale_buyer">Klient hurtowy - srebrny</option><option value="wholesale_tax_free">Klient hurtowy - złoty</option>

Comment: I've updated the code accordingly

Comment: Excelent. Thank you so much :) 
missing echo '' :)

Comment: You should delete the answer you added

Comment: So, how can i set default option for page? For example: If is my_account - role customer, if other - shop_manager ? 

This actions is added for "add_action('register_form',

Answer (score 0):

So, following the topic. This is code for add select role in register page in Wordpress.

```
//1. Add a new form element...
add_action('register_form', 'myplugin_register_form');
function myplugin_register_form() {

    global $wp_roles;

    echo '<select name="role" class="input">';
    foreach ($wp_roles->roles as $key => $value):
        if ( in_array( $key, array('customer', 'shop_manager') ) )
            echo '<option value="' . $key . '">' . $value['name'] . '</option>';
    endforeach;
    echo '</select>';

}

//2. Add validation.
add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'myplugin_registration_errors', 10, 3 );
function myplugin_registration_errors( $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) {

    if ( empty( $_POST['role'] ) || ! empty( $_POST['role'] ) && trim( $_POST['role'] ) == '' ) {
         $errors->add( 'role_error', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: You must include a role.', 'mydomain' ) );
    }

    return $errors;
}

//3. Finally, save our extra registration user meta.
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_user_register' );
function myplugin_user_register( $user_id ) {

   $user_id = wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $user_id, 'role' => $_POST['role'] ) );
}
```